# Why does the function `dump` not exist in twig file?

Tags: symfony, twig

I don't know why it shows this error

```
The function "dump" does not exist in twig file
```

while I have already writen in `config.yml` file:

```
services:
product_store.twig.extension.debug:
    class: Twig_Extension_Debug
    tags:
         - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

and in twig file I try to dump  with:

```
{{ dump(product) }}
```

Comment: Not sure if you copied it wrong but you need to indent all lines below the services: line

Comment: @CarlosGranados ah... I just posted the same answer :S

Comment: If the indent was wrong I bet he would have an error when loading the configuration for a non-existing section.

Comment: @BorisGuery Yeah, you are right

Comment: You're right. Deleted my dumb answer :-[

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using? This was only available after 2.0.9

Comment: @CarlosGranados I am using symfony2.1

Comment: thanks to every one...may be this is my fault and i am going to check my whole code again.

Comment: i used the php way for a silex app - maybe ist helps:
/* @var Twig_Environment $twig */
# http://blog.bitexpert.de/tag/silex/
$twig->addExtension(new BDM\Twig\Extension\MyTwigExtension());

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer from lifo encourages you to use the [`debug`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/debug.html) tag, but the `debug` tag `{% debug product %}` was deprecated in Twig 1.5 and replaced with the [`dump`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function `{{ dump(product) }}`.

The proper extension to enable as of Symfony Standard Edition 2.0.9 is `Twig_Extension_Debug` and should be added to `app/config/config_dev.yml` so it is only loaded in the dev environment:

```
services:
    twig.extension.debug:
        class: Twig_Extension_Debug
        tags: [{ name: 'twig.extension' }]
```

You should then be able to use `{{ dump(product) }}` in your templates.

If a problem still exists, you can try a few things:

1. Use `php app/console container:debug twig.extension.debug --env=dev` to ensure the dependency injection container is properly picking up your service definition.

   ```
   [container] Information for service twig.extension.debug

   Service Id       twig.extension.debug
   Class            Twig_Extension_Debug
   Tags
       - twig.extension                 ()
   Scope            container
   Public           yes
   Synthetic        no
   Required File    -
   ```
2. Open the compiled dependency injection container class for your dev environment and search for `Twig_Extension_Debug` to see if any other service was already defined to use it. This file lives at `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php`
3. Ensure the parameter `%kernel.debug%` is true.
4. Ensure you're using Twig 1.5 or later.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the update. My answer is no longer completely correct.

Comment: 4. How do you check whether you are using Twig 1.5 or later? I am using Symfony 2.5 but my composer.json only lists "twig/extensions": "~1.1.0", so it seems like the main twig is hard coded in symfony because when I do `composer update` it updated from 1.15 to 1.16.

Comment: Suggest Improvement to Answer: If the app/console says "[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] The service definition "twig.extension.debug" does not exist." What do you suggest?

Comment: Suggested Improvement to Answer: If Twig_Extension_Debug is added as an extension in that file `$instance->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());` what does that mean and what do you suggest?

Comment: FYI, Twig debug is enabled by default in Symfony 2.5 if you have your config setup correctly. So I believe this is the recommended method for newer installs: symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#debugging

Answer (score 1):

First, "dump" is not actually the command, its "debug". Second, your config syntax is a little messed up. It should look something like this:

```
services:
    twig.extension.debug:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then you can use it in your templates like this: `{% debug var %}` -- **Note the {%%} braces. Debug does not work within {{}} braces because its a TAG and not a FUNCTION.**

Comment: `{% debug %}` was deprecated in Twig 1.5 and replaced with the `{{ dump() }}` function. See my answer for updated usage.

Comment: This worked for me. Must be using an older Twig version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the reason:

Where have you put the

```
services:
  product_store.twig.extension.debug:
  class:        Twig_Extension_Debug
  tags:
     - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

It should be in config.yml of your boundle in:

```
nameOfTheBoundle/Resources/config/config.yml
```

and not in config.yml of the projeft in:

```
app/config/config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. All I had to do was to enable the DebugBundle in AppKernel (in dev/test environments only):

```
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
```

and that was it. No need to register any services.

Comment: This question is related to symfony2 old version. Please see date !!